# Call promise function on second animation of element not first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am creating an app with phonegap, I am validating a form client side  using jquery. Any errors drop down and 'cover' the status bar at the very top like snapchat does when there is no connection.

To do this I am hiding the status bar when the error is called, the error slides down and displays for 3 seconds before sliding up. I want to use the promise function to wait until the error has slid up before showing the status bar again but all I can manage is hiding the status bar and showing the status bar again directly after the error slides down.

Code (J-query):

```
 function check_password() {

  var password_length = $("#password_box").val().length;

  if (password_length < 5) {
    StatusBar.hide();
    $("#error_password").html("Password must be greater than 5 characters");
    $("#error_password").slideDown();
    $("#password_box").addClass('red_border');

    $(function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
          $("#error_password").slideUp('fast')
           }, 3000);

    });

    error_password = true;

  } else{
    $("#error_password").hide();
  }
 }
```

Css:

```
.error {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    background-color:#a50d2e;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1%;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have a var say called, showError, default this to true.   Then at the start of your functiion do, if (!showError) return; showError = false;  then lastly after you slideUp, set showError = true;

Comment: `slideDown` and `slideUp` both have callbacks, and both return deferreds, if you show us where you're showing this statusbar after the error has slid down, maybe we can help you

Comment: I will place the css code for these boxes in the code.

The way the validation works is these are hidden by default until someone types something and focus' out of the input box, it then checks it's valid. If not it displays the error message

Comment: @adeneo They don't return deferred, but you can chain into `.promise()` and get the same thing. I checked the jQuery docs just now, it says it chains the incoming selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using the `slideDown` completion callback:

```
$("#error_password").slideDown(function() {
    // This function runs when the slideDown is complete
});
```

Another way is with `.promise()`, which has the added benefit of running after all of the matching elements have completed their animation (worthwhile when the selector matches more than one element):

```
$("#error_password").slideDown().promise().then(function() {
    // This function runs when the slideDown is complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect or the best possible way of doing it but it's a short fix and might help some people in some scenarios.

If someone has a 'proper' way of actually using the promise on the slideUp portion it would still be appreciated.

All I did was use a setTimeOut function below the first one which delays the animation for a set amount of time when it's called.

I delayed it 3200ms instead of 3000ms as this gives the slideUp time to complete and the status bar looks like it was just hidden behind the error the whole time.

jquery:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      StatusBar.show();
}, 3200);
```